# Missing part from the JSON

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have hit a wall that I cant find the way around. I have a JSON file that I am trying to decode but there is a part of the JSON that is missing. I always get nil even though I know that there is supposed to be data there.

This is the first part of the JSON file

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "points",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": { "osm_id": "755", 
                  "name": "Majorstuen", 
                  "other_tags":      "\"bus\"=>\"yes\",\"network\"=>\"Ruter\",\"public_transport\"=>\"stop_position\"" }, 
                  "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 10.7160479, 59.9296625 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": { "osm_id": "1188", 
                  "name": "Arnes", 
                  "highway": "bus_stop", 
                  "other_tags": "\"ref:nsrq\"=>\"82139\"" }, 
                  "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 16.919517, 68.3459 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": { "osm_id": "1194", 
                  "name": "Skjellneset", 
                  "highway": "bus_stop", 
                  "other_tags": "\"ref:nsrq\"=>\"82148\"" }, 
                  "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 16.938766, 68.34916 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": { "osm_id": "1202", 
                  "name": "Osen", 
                  "highway": "bus_stop", 
                  "other_tags": "\"ref:nsrq\"=>\"82152\"" }, 
                  "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 16.952982, 68.352551 ] } }
]}
```

Here is my Struct:

```
struct This:Codable {
    let type: String?
    let name: String?
    let crs: CRS
    let features: [Features]

    struct CRS: Codable {
        let type: String?
        let properties: CRSProperties

        struct CRSProperties: Codable {
            let name: String?

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case name
            }
        }

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case type
            case properties
        }
    }

    struct Features: Codable {
        let type: String?
        let properties: FeaturesProperties

        struct FeaturesProperties: Codable {
            let osmId: String?
            let name: String?
            let highway: String?
            let otherTags: String?
            let geo: FeaturesPropertiesGeometry?

            struct FeaturesPropertiesGeometry: Codable {
                let type: String
                let coordinates: [Double]

                enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                    case type
                    case coordinates
                }
            }

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case osmId = "osm_id"
                case name
                case highway
                case otherTags = "other_tags"
                case geo = "geometry"
            }
        }

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case type
            case properties
        }
    }
}
```

Then here is what I use to decode the JSON

```
guard let asset = NSDataAsset(name: "NN") else {
               print("NN JSON not here")
               return
           }

    do {
        let deco = JSONDecoder()
        this = try deco.decode(This.self, from: asset.data)
    }catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```

My problem is that I dont get the geometry data into "this: This". If I print every line then from "this" then the result for "geo" is always nil.

This is a printed line.
"Features(type: Optional("Feature"), properties: mokkingaroud.This.Features.FeaturesProperties(osmId: Optional("10587816"), name: Optional("YX Evje"), highway: nil, otherTags: Optional("\"amenity\"=>\"fuel\",\"branch\"=>\"Evje\",\"brand\"=>\"YX\",\"email\"=>\"evje@st.yx.no\",\"fuel:adblue\"=>\"yes\",\"fuel:diesel\"=>\"yes\",\"fuel:HGV_diesel\"=>\"yes\",\"fuel:octane_95\"=>\"yes\",\"fuel:taxfree_diesel\"=>\"yes\",\"hgv\"=>\"yes\",\"phone\"=>\"+47 37 92 95 60\",\"ref:yx\"=>\"561\""), ***geo: nil***))"

Any suggestions please.

Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `coordinates` is not a `String` I'd use:

```
struct This:Codable {
    let name, type: String?
    let features: [Features]
}
struct Features: Codable {
    let type: String?
    let properties: [Properties]
    let geometry: [Geometry]

}
struct Properties:Codable {
    let name, osm_id, other_tags: String?
}
struct Geometry:Codable {
    let type: String?
    let coordinates: [Double]
}
```

Comment: This helped, I saw what I did wrong there. I placed geometry at the wrong place in the struct.

Comment: If this answer helped you please make sure you approve it as the right answer by checking the gray checkmark below the vote section.